# Position Sticky to unnested element CSS only?

Tags: css, position, sticky

I'm trying to stick both a header bar AND a logo to the top of the page.  I have the header bar working great with **position:sticky** but the logo resides inside of a different div which is not nested (due to other existing elements).  What would I need to do to make the following LOGO also sticky?

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xmwyncva/)

```css
.sticky {position: sticky; top: 0; }

.header-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top:55px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1c1209;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;    
}

.nav-logo-area {background-color: #076064; height: 200px; transform: none;}
.logo {  width: 111px; margin: 0 auto;}

.content-area {background-color: #ACE0D5; min-height:1200px; height: 1200px;}
```

```html
<!-- TOP ROW -->        
<div class="header-row sticky">
  header row here
</div>
    
<!-- LOGO & NAV --> 
<div class="nav-logo-area">
  This height set because nav menus and other content will go here.
  <div class="logo sticky">
    <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-bird-symbols-png-logo-0.png" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
</div>
    
<!-- MAIN CONTENT & BELOW -->   
<div class="content-area">
  Some main content here. Added some height to the div to we can see the scroll action.
</div>
```

Is this possible with CSS only?  The existing layout has a TON of additional content so simply "moving" the logo div to a different location would require a lot of repositioning work so I am hoping to accomplish this with what I have here.  Thank you so much.

Comment: display:contents to `.nav-logo-area` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position sticky will be related to the parent element with `position: relative`.
You need to use `position: sticky` on the logo with `top: 0`, in this way your logo will stick to its parent element.
I added a black background to clearly show the border of the image.

```css
.sticky {position: sticky; top: 0; }

.header-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top:55px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1c1209;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #FFF;    
}

#nav-logo-area {background-color: #076064; height: 200px; transform: none; position: relative }
.logo {  width: 111px; margin: 0 auto}
img { width: 100%; background-color: black }

.content-area {background-color: #ACE0D5; min-height:1200px; height: 1200px;}
```

```html
<!-- TOP ROW -->        
<div class="header-row sticky">
  header row here
</div>
    
<!-- LOGO & NAV --> 
<div id="nav-logo-area">
  This height set because nav menus and other content will go here.
  <div class="logo sticky">
    <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-bird-symbols-png-logo-0.png" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
</div>
    
<!-- MAIN CONTENT & BELOW -->   
<div style="" class="content-area">
  Some main content here. Added some height to the div to we can see the scroll action.
</div>
```

Comment: That was a typo on my part while I was cleaning up the code to paste here.  I'll fix the original.  Fixing it doesn't seem to completely stick the logo

Comment: @RodeoRamsey Where do you want to stick the logo? I assumed you wanted to stick the logo in the `nav-logo-area`, do you want to stick it at the top of the page?

Comment: I want to stick it at top:0 right where it falls on the page.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. It's almost as if when the bottom of the `nav-logo-area` defined height hits the bottom of the logo, it pushes it up.

Comment: Yeah, position sticky is relative to the parent, so when the parent scrolls out of the view so its children do. I'm afraid this limit can't be overcome without html modifications

Comment: Update to select this answer since it was most applicable to my situation, and to say I was able to restructure the html to suit my needs. Thanks!